# Importrange but only include certain values

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a new sheet from Google Form data which only imports  cell data that matches specific criteria. Respondents have five response options for a number of questions (all questions have the same five options). I want the new sheet to only show the data in the cells that fit my criteria and the cells that don't, should be blank. I would like all rows and column formatting to remain the same.

I've got the import range part down, but I don't know should I use query, filter, if, or some other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the same spreadsheet, `QUERY` works well. You could also use `QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(` or just `IMPORTRANGE` if you want it to go to a different spreadsheet.

As Rubén said, if you want to maintain all the formatting, without manually doing it yourself on the destination sheet, you'll need to use script.

[Query Reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

**EDIT**

See `Sheet3` [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsSet_beH805Y7evJgpF1FPdcxXYAWq3_sSpDLb2i-Q/edit?usp=sharing). Make a copy to edit.

Any cell with a blue background has a formula. The main one is below.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Form Responses 1'!D3:DD="","",SWITCH('Form Responses 1'!D3:DD,$D$1,"",$E$1,"",'Form Responses 1'!D3:DD)))`

You will not be able to edit those columns. If you need to edit (like the "Comments/Adaptations" columns, you could modify the formula above and apply it column by column.

If that works, please click the green check mark to accept the answer!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll share an example sheet so we're on the same page as my description may not have been clear. I still can't figure this out :) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fdFKGJQiI7Q2F9GRlDJnwXj0ftSV84ERzKIgGpQdjE/edit?usp=sharing    I want Sheet 2 to look exactly like the Form Response sheet with all the "Frequently = 60-79%" and "Almost Always = 80-100%" values removes, leaving only "About 1/2 the time = 40-59%," "Hardly Ever = 20-39%" and "Rarely/Never = 0-19%."

Answer (score 0):

Beside the number format, any formula keeps the format of the source range, so if your the format includes fonts styles, bold, italics, colors, etc., instead of a formula you should use a script.